# What is the difference between FROM and SELECT clause in hibernate.Is there any semantic difference in terms of results?

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the difference between FROM and SELECT clause in HQL.Is there any semantic difference in terms of results?

I googled, but could not find any justifying answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Marko's anwser is complete but you can read examples from the official Hibernate documentation.

- [Select clause](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-select) : return selected objects in a query result set
- [From clause](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-from) : return class instances

It depends on your needs but you don't need to specify select clause in your HQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

These two queries are semantically quite discinct:

- a FROM query asks for a complete object and the return value is accordingly one or more instances of the persistent class;
- a SELECT query asks for a *projection* of the entity and in the basic case the return value is one or more arrays of values being asked for. You can also order the values being put into a map, list, or a dedicated DTO object using the form `select new map/list/className`.

Comment: Thanks Marco..really helpful.Could you give mean example.